# emberjs automatic model binding/creation

Tags: ember.js

When I use a dynamic segment in the Ember.Router then will ember automatically identify the Model, call find(index) on it, and set the result to the content of the controller. Is this correct?

If Yes, how is the Model identified? By the name that I've given in the "connectOutlet" function?

Is there something like this for routes without an dynamic Part? If Not, why are is the View and the Controller auto-generated and binded, and the Model not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model type is provided to the `Ember.Route` through the `modelType` attribute:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/:stuff_id',
    modelType: 'App.Stuff',

    connectOutlets: function(router, stuff) {
        ... // work with Stuff instance 'stuff' here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, thanks. I've tried to make an example now, but it seems not working: http://jsfiddle.net/bhEtU/ I think the App.ItemList.find function should be called, when I enter the detail.

Comment: Thanks. Two things: the route in the URL should be '/item/detail/1', not '/item/detail/undefined'. And, the content of the detail route should not be a single ItemList element, it should be a ItemDetail element. So the content should be ItemDetail.find(context). I hope U understand what I mean.

Comment: You should use ember data to manage your model instances, that may be the reason why you have undefined id in the URL route.

Comment: Shouldnt it be possible, to manage the models manuelly? With the information on [link](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/), i think the router is just calling App.Model.find(index). I've manuelly implemented this function. but its not called.

Comment: I think that as of today, routing implementation is strongly related to ember data (through a lot of implicit expectations: Store, primary key, ...) so you should experience really fewer issues if using it in a nominal way. Support will also be better & quicker (e.g: I will be glad to help you in directions which obviously improve my own mastering... exploring corner cases through ad hoc implementations does not excites me that much)

Comment: Hm, the Problem is that my Backend API is really not campatible to a normal data scheme. But I will try to map it to ember.data if I can find a moment for it this week.

Comment: Can you provide further info? Do you rely on relational storage or not? (FYI, there is WIP for noSQL backend support, but ETA is not yet known...)

Comment: Its a strange backend. Theoretical relational, but often non-relational. I just see a simple denormalized layer, because the original layer is to complex for the WebApp. And, everything is slow! So I have special performance optimized getter functions who just provide the necessary informations. So I have for example a lot of getter functions for the item, many list getters, but all lists are the same view. And one detail function whos only provide the detail informations. But in fact I need most the times just read access, and some special actions on the records.(which cache-resets)

Comment: Ok, so what really matter is to be able to present data 'as if' there were from relational storage. If you are able to implement a (~thin?) layer serving you data, you're done! :)

Good luck, and see ya!